# WCF Settings concurrency and code check

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have the following settings for my WCF Service;

InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple

My methods look like this;

```
  public List<MessagesAPI> GetInboxMessagesByUserID(string UserID)
    {
        int intUserID = 0;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(UserID))
            intUserID = int.Parse(UserID);

        List<MessagesAPI> listMessages = new List<MessagesAPI>();
        UserMessageCache userMessageCache = new UserMessageCache();

        ApiHelper apiHelper = new ApiHelper();
        string strUserTimeZone = apiHelper.GetUsersTimeZone(intUserID);

        listMessages = userMessageCache.APIGetUserInboxMessagesByUserID(intUserID, strUserTimeZone);

        return listMessages;
    }
```

Am i likely to have any problems, do i need to do any locking or is my code good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `InstanceContextMode.PerCall` together with `ConcurrencyMode.Multiple` doesn't make sense. It is same as `InstanceContextMode.PerCall` and `ConcurrencyMode.Single`. The reason is that `InstanceContext` mode determines how is service instanced and `ConcurrencyMode` determines how many concurrent requests can be processed by single service instance. Once you set `InstanceContextMode` to `PerCall` you are explicitly saying that each request will have its own service instance so there can never be one service instance processing multiple concurrent requests.

Comment: @ladislav-mrnka should i only set the InstanceContextMode?

Comment: @pmillio: Yes or perhaps you don't need to set `InstanceContextMode`. For some bindings like basicHttp or webHttp `PerCall` is default value.

Answer (score 2):

[InstanceContextMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.instancecontextmode.aspx) determines when a new instance of your service type is created and [ConcurrencyMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.concurrencymode.aspx) determines how many requests can be serviced simultaneously. That means your settings will allow multiple requests to be serviced with each request having its own instance of your service.

With that in mind, you shouldn't have any "issues" in terms of thread safety as I don't see any static members (although I can't be sure since I don't know how your other classes are defined). However, you may run into some performance issues since you're creating a new instance per request, depending on your request load.

As a note, you typically worry about thread safety when you have shared resources; hence why I mentioned static members even though each request is being serviced by its own instance.

Comment: Thanks, i am putting this on the Cloud, will this help. Sorry if my questions sound silly.